# Asp.net Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to create a Folder object which has files and other folders in it and also itself might be the part of another folder. Here is what I have:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual FolderSettings FolderSettings { get; set; }

    private ICollection<FolderSettings> _folders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FolderSettings> Folders
    {
        get { return _folders ?? (_folders = new HashSet<FolderSettings>()); }
        set { _folders = value; }
    }

    private ICollection<Files> _files{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<File> Files
    {
        get { return _files?? (_files = new HashSet<File>()); }
        set { _files= value; }
    }
}

public class FolderSettings
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("MyFoder")]
    public Guid FolderId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Folder MyFoder{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RootFolder")]
    public Guid? RootFolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder RootFolder { get; set; }        
}
```

The Folder settings object might have much more property I just simplified it. The error what I get is:

Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: EF complains because it can't determine if Folder or FolderSettings is the dependant property (also, typo in ForeignKey("Foder")?). Whenever it tries to, for example, add one of these, it has to add the other member first, which it can't because the other member has to be added first, and so on. Make one end optional or define the principle and the dependant entity.

Comment: sorry for the typo. FolderSettings contains setting for the folder which belongs to it and also stores the root foleder as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

EF does not discover that

```
public virtual FolderSettings FolderSettings { get; set; }
```

is the inverse of the Foreignkey `MyFoder`. add this line above it and your model will be understood:

```
[InverseProperty("MyFoder")]
```

---

In FolderSettings, Add a property

```
public Folder Folder { get; set; }
```

and correct the spelling `ForeignKey('Foder')`.
EF will start to work.

Just please note that in class Folder, the Folders property is of type `ICollection<FolderSettings>` but from your explanation it looks like `ICollection<Folder>` is what you really mean

Here is the code:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("MyFoder")]
    public virtual FolderSettings FolderSettings { get; set; }

    private ICollection<FolderSettings> _folders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FolderSettings> Folders
    {
        get { return _folders ?? (_folders = new HashSet<FolderSettings>()); }
        set { _folders = value; }
    }

    private ICollection<File> _files { get; set; }
    public ICollection<File> Files
    {
        get { return _files ?? (_files = new HashSet<File>()); }
        set { _files = value; }
    }
}

public class File
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FolderSettings
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Folder")]
    public Guid FolderId { get; set; }
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }
    public virtual MVAppGroup AppGroup { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public Guid? GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual MVAppGroup Group { get; set; }
}

public class MVAppGroup
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FolderSettings> FolderSettings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MVAppGroup> MVAppGroups { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var a = new A())
        {
            a.Folders.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. ICollection<FolderSettings> is correct. If I store the root folder in the FolderSettings then it is easier to just update the folder settings when I want to update the root of the folder

Comment: BTW, I tested the code on a console application and only doing two first changes, let it do the work. You can ignore the last change if that is really not your intention.

Comment: I was trying but I couldn't understand what to do. could you just post your version of FolderSerrings class?

Comment: I have modified my code since this. The AppGroup is actually in the original problem which I have simplified to files and folders. Please chack my modified code I believe it should make clear what I wanted to do

Comment: EF does not discover that `public virtual FolderSettings FolderSettings { get; set; }` is the inverse of the Foreignkey MyFoder. add this line above it and your model will be understood: `[InverseProperty("MyFoder")]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?